# Can not check the duplicate data in database using PHP,Mysql and Angular.js

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

i am finding little bit difficult to check duplicate data from database using MYsql,PHP and angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

addUser.php:

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$user_name=$request->user_name;
$user_email=$request->user_email;
$mob_no=$request->mob_no;
$login_name=$request->login_name;
$password=$request->password;
$user_status=$request->user_status;
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Oditek123@');
mysql_select_db('go_fasto', $con);
$selquery = "SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE login_name='".$login_name."' and mob_no='".$mob_no."' and email='" . $user_email . "'";
$selres = mysql_query($selquery);
if(mysql_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
{
    $erresult=mysql_fetch_array($selres);
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    $erresult['msg'] = 'This user login name or mobile no or email is already exist.';
}else{
    $qry ='INSERT INTO db_user (user_name,email,mob_no,login_name,password,user_status) values ("' . $user_name . '","' . $user_email . '","' . $mob_no . '","' .$login_name . '","' . $password . '","' . $user_status . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);

    $user_type = 5;
    $display_name = $user_name."_admin";
    $qry ='INSERT INTO db_Admin_Master (user_type,user_name,display_name,password) values ("' . $user_type . '","' . $login_name . '","' . $display_name . '","' .$password . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);



    $query='SELECT * from db_user order by user_id desc';
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if ($result) {
            $result['msg'] = "New User has added successfully";
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
             $result['msg'] =  "Sorry, User could not added ";
        }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

If you will check my code i am checking three column such as `login_name,email and mob_no` from database and checking it inside if statement.Here even if i am inserting the same data again it is not checking and else part is executing.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you `echo mysql_num_rows($selres )` . Check that what result it provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$selquery = "SELECT *
    FROM db_user
    WHERE login_name='".$login_name."'
        OR mob_no='".$mob_no."'
        OR email='" . $user_email . "'";
```

use OR instead of AND try